# Can IIS Express support reverse proxies?

Tags: reverse-proxy, iis-express

I'd like to set up a reverse proxy in IIS Express but it doesn't appear that Application Request Routing is supported (though I can't find anything which officially documents this).

My goal is to get a web server to proxy an incoming request to http://web.server/api/example to a second server (e.g. http://some.api.server/example) where web.server is running on IIS Express.

How might this be achieved?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No...you need ARR (application request routing) for doing this and arr can be installed only if you have IIS7/7.5 is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Even I tried the same thing. After searching on the net for 2 whole days, I finally found this
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2011/08/25/return-404-4-not-found-when-url-rewrite.aspx ([Wayback link](https://web.archive.org/web/20110915042756/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2011/08/25/return-404-4-not-found-when-url-rewrite.aspx))

Scroll down to the end of the blog and it tells you that you cannot implement reverse proxy on IIS Express

Comment: "Scroll down to the end of the blog and it tells you that you cannot implement reverse proxy on IIS Express" - that's not what the article says though, it just says you need ARR - the page makes no reference to IIS Express.