# read mp3 stream and echo back to client in php

Tags: php, proxy, mp3

What I intend to achieve, is a page that when a client is to connect, the page is to constantly read from a local ice-cast server (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/stream.mp3`), and echo the stream back to the client, from there, the client can be play it back in a basic audio tag.

```
<?php
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="stream.mp3"');
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
print file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:443/stream.mp3");
```

With this code it only eats up ram and returns nothing useful to the client, I'm thinking something along the lines of waiting until a megabyte buffer is full, then echoing it to the client.  But idk, so yeah.

Please note that I'm not that experienced with php.  Thanks!

Comment: I would prefer to do that on the level of the http server, by proxying the ice cast server through your http server. That way php is not used at all.

Comment: Would this be possible with IIS Express?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea about that. So MS did the same thing again as with MS-Outlook and MS-Outlook-Express? _Why_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_contents` attempts to read a stream up to the end, and since you're trying to read from a broadcast server there will be no end.

If HTML5 is an option, the following may work.

```
<audio autoplay>
  <source src="http://127.0.0.1:443/stream.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">      
</audio>
```

Alternative solution:

```
<?php
ob_start();
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="stream.mp3"');
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$handle = fopen("http://127.0.0.1:443/stream.mp3");

while (($data = fread($handle, $bufferSize)) { //Buffer size needs to be large enough to not break audio up while getting the next part
      echo $data;
      ob_flush();
      flush();
      set_time_limit(30); // Reset the script execution time to prevent timeouts since this page will probably never terminate. 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I intend to host ice-cast locally, and have the http server port forwarded.  And then the clients connecting to the http server will only be allowed to access ../stream.mp3 somehow, without access to any other part of ice-cast's interface.

Comment: I've noted down an alternative (not sure if it works, haven't tested it, but I don't see why it wouldn't). IIS Express unfortunately does not support reverse-proxying (according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492965/can-iis-express-support-reverse-proxies)

Comment: PLease share solution to this and tag me